# regex to match all *texttexttext in a string

Tags: php, javascript, html, regex

I need a regex that will match all strings starting with * until it meets a <

so in this block of text: `bob went to the *store and he bought a toy and <then he went outside *and went to his car for <a ride.`

it would match `bob went to the *store and he bought a toy and` and `and went to his car for`

and if there is no "<" it will match all until the end of the line

Comment: According to your description, your example should match `store and he bought a toy and ` and `and went to his car for `. Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
<pre>
<?
$s = 'bob went to the *store and he bought a toy and <then he went outside *and went to his car for <a ride.';

preg_match_all("/\*([^<]+)/", $s, $matched); 
print_r($matched);
?>
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => *store and he bought a toy and 
            [1] => *and went to his car for 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => store and he bought a toy and 
            [1] => and went to his car for 
        )

)
```

Comment: Can you make a new line character break the match as well?

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like:

With PHP:

```
preg_match_all("#\*(.+?)<#", $stringWithText, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
$mCount = count($matches);

foreach ($matches as $match)
    echo "Matched: " . $match[1] . "<br/>";
```

If you want to skip the end "<" the change the expression to `#\*(.+?)<?#` and if you want to allow line changes, use these flags:

```
preg_match_all("#\*(.+?)<#si", $stringWithText, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

Notice the si flags trailing the expression

Hope it helps

Comment: How can I make it match until there it finds a "<" so if there is no "<" it will continue matching from the start of the *

Answer (score 1):

Try `\*(.+?)<`

You can use this tool to experiment with regex: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

**EDIT**
To keep matching to a `<` OR to the end of the string, use:

`\*(.+?)[<|$.*]`

Comment: It works, but how can I modify to match even if there is no < at the end so it will continue matching until it finds a "<"

Comment: Will this stop matching at new line as well?

Comment: No... you didn't ask for that.  `\*(.+?)[<|\n|$|\r.*]` - that will match newline chars from DOS and Linux.  HOWEVER, since there are so many `OR` clauses there, a line break in the midst of a match between * and < would only match to the line break instead.

Answer (score 1):

I would use something like this

```
(?<=\*).*?(?=<|$)
```

See it here on [Regexr](http://regexr.com?2u0kf)

`(?<=\*)` is a look behind, it matches no character, but it ensures, that the character before is a `*`

`.*?` matches everything non greedy

`(?=<|$)` is a look ahead, it matches no character, but it ensures, that the following character is a `<` or a `$` (row end) ==> use the m (multiline) modifier, otherwise the `$` will match only the end of the string and not the end of the row.